# Integration involving modified bessel function, exponential and power

Tags: pr.probability, integration, integral-transforms, hypergeometric-functions, bessel-functions

I need to find the following integration.

$$
\int_0^a e^{-(N-1)x}(\sqrt{4x}K_{1}(\sqrt{4x}))^N
$$
where 
$$
a>0, \quad N \geq 1
$$

Any help will be much appreciated.

BR

Frank

Comment: How does this come up?  It might be that the problem that gave rise to this integral is more tractable in its original formulation.  (That's one reason why we ask for context in mathoverflow questions.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your interest. This problem is an assignment given to me by my supervisor and unfortunately I don't know anything about the origin of the problem. All I know is that if i try to solve it for N=1 using wolfram alpha then i get an answer in the form of Meijer-G function.